# Product of nilpotent matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ complex matrices  and

let  $[A,B] = AB - BA$.

Question: If  $A , B$ and  $[A,B]$  are all nilpotent matrices,

is it necessarily true that  $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = 0$?

If,in fact, $[A,B] = 0$, then we can take $A$ and $B$ to be strictly upper triangular matrices so that the answer would be yes in this very special case.

Comment: If $\operatorname{rank} [A,B] = 1$ then $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=0$. If in your problem above you change $[A,B]$ by $A+B$ then the conclusion  $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=0$ becomes true for all $n$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no.

Take $A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$, $B=XAX^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\end{array}\right)$, where we chose $X=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.

Then $[A,B]= \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ is nilpotent, but we have $AB=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=-1\not=0$.

Comment: Nice example! Did you find it just by "random" search, or is there an idea behind it?

Answer (score 3):

No. While the conjecture is true for $n=2$ and computer experiments suggest that it may also be true for $n=3$, counterexamples are abundant when $n=4$. Let $A$ be the $4\times4$ Jordan block. The following $B$s are some computer generated random counterexamples that satisfy the condition $B^4=(AB-BA)^4=0$ but $\mathrm{trace}(AB)\neq0$.
\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ -1&-1&-1&0\\ 1&0&0&0},
&\pmatrix{
 4& -4&  4& -6\\
 2& -2&  2& -3\\
14&-14& 14&-13\\
16&-16& 16&-16
},\\
\\
\pmatrix{
 1&  1&  1&  2\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
 1&  2&  1&  2\\
-1& -2& -1& -2\\
},
&\pmatrix{
-1& -1&  0&  0\\
 1&  1&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  1\\
 1&  1&  0&  0\\
}.
\end{align*}